# How can I define a new symbol in latex (with its own image)?

Tags: graphics, symbols

I'm new to LaTeX and I'm using TeX Writer for iOS and I want to insert a new command "\dotplus" (symbolically: `$\dotplus$`) on my .text to .pdf. All I did was:

[image]

And I got three errors:

[image]

I have also saved the symbol's picture to PDF..

Comment: @Mark Do you have a specific  link that can help me ?

Comment: there is already a `\dotplus` symbol command defined if you `\usepackage{amssymb}` (the symbol is included in `amsfonts`, which is loaded automatically by `amssymb`).

Comment: @barbarabeeton so I type \usepackage{assymb}{\dotplus} and I'm done ?

Comment: `\usepackage{amssymb}` goes in the preamble.  then you can use `\dotplus` (in math) in the body of your document.  (a lot of other symbols become available too,)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use **`\includegraphics`** you need to add **`\usepackage{graphicx}`** in your preamble (at the beginning of your document).
And fix the `\newcommand{}` statement like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\dotplus}{\includegraphics[width=0.2in]{/dotplus.jpg}}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\dotplus

\end{document}
```

Comment: Let me try it. I will warn you if that won't work

Comment: What is that "{graphicx}" for ?

Comment: It tells the TeX engine to include/use the package *graphicx* which contains the function `\includegraphics` you want to use. Otherwise the engine won't know what to do with the command `\includegraphics`.

Comment: So what I have to type inside {graphicx} ?

Comment: Well, I typed: \newcommand*\dotplus{\usepackage{width=0.2in}{\dotplus.jpg}}. I got an error: "can be used only in preamble "

Comment: Check out my initial answer, I added your example with corrections. The only thing I can't check is the path to your image, as I don't know where it resides on your phone or in the editor.

Comment: @user180321 -- your post has been migrated to the tex site, not deleted.  you may have to register for the tex site to be able to accept or upvote an answer.

Answer (score 2):

there is a `\dotplus` symbol in the `amsfonts` collection.  insert

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
```

in your preamble.  then you can use `\dotplus` (in math) in the body
of your document.  `amssymb` loads `amsfonts` automatically, so you
get access to a lot of other math symbols as well.

actually, this question should be considered a duplicate of
[How to look up a symbol or identify a math alphabet?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14) but since you're coming from a
totally non-tex site, i've given a detailed answer.

Comment: @user180321 -- the "history" of this question shows that you're coming from the apple site.  if you're going to be using tex, and think you might have more questions, please register also for this site -- tex.stackexchange.com.